# What does the put method do for dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've tried to search everywhere, but nothing seems to apply to this case. Here's the code in question:

```
class ParkingFloor:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name
    self.__handicapped_spots = {}
    self.__compact_spots = {}
    self.__large_spots = {}
    self.__motorbike_spots = {}
    self.__electric_spots = {}
    self.__info_portals = {}
    self.__display_board = ParkingDisplayBoard()

  def add_parking_spot(self, spot):
    switcher = {
      ParkingSpotType.HANDICAPPED: self.__handicapped_spots.put(spot.get_number(), spot),
      ParkingSpotType.COMPACT: __compact_spots.put(spot.get_number(), spot),
      ParkingSpotType.LARGE: __large_spots.put(spot.get_number(), spot),
      ParkingSpotType.MOTORBIKE: __motorbike_spots.put(spot.get_number(), spot),
      ParkingSpotType.ELECTRIC: __electric_spots.put(spot.get_number(), spot),
    }
    switcher.get(spot.get_type(), 'Wrong parking spot type')
```

I know that the `get` method simply retrieves a value from the specified dictionary, and returns the second argument if it isn't found. I'm assuming `put` simply adds a key-value pair to the dictionary, but I can't confirm from anywhere if this is the case since all 'put method' search results seem to be about `requests`.

Comment: There is no `put()` for `dict`. Did you mean to read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)?

Comment: Like @quamrana said, there's no `dict.put()`, even in Python 3.9 and 2.7. Maybe that class does something extra to modify `self.__handicapped_spots`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Or maybe whoever wrote this got confused with Java's [`HashMap.put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-)

Comment: I think @wjandrea is right. This is from an OOP course, and they have both python and java code examples. I think they must've copied and pasted from the java code without changing it into python. Extremely frustrating. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, as mentioned in the comments, python `dict` does not have a `put` method. If that is the case, why the code does not throw an error?

Your code example is not full, but my guess is that the following line returns `None`:

```
switcher.get(spot.get_type(), 'Wrong parking spot type')
```

Lets simplify your code and create a mock example to see what is happening:

```
# define class and function
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None


def Bar():
    print(True)


# init the class
foo = Foo()
```

Now lets examine what happens when we define switcher and try to get its value:

```
# if we define the dict like this
# calling a get method will return None

switcher = {
    foo: Bar()
}

switcher.get(foo)
# returns None
```

Lets modify this a bit:

```
# if we define the dict like this
# calling a get method will return a function
switcher = {
    foo: Bar
}

switcher.get(foo)
# <function Bar at 0x000001916A71D820> 

# we can now execute it like this
switcher.get(foo)()
# prints True
```

So the code does not fail or raise any exceptions because the following line returns `None` and `put` method is never being tried to be called on `dict`:

```
switcher.get(spot.get_type(), 'Wrong parking spot type')
```